# MySQL 8 update with Replace() or Regex

Tags: mysql, json, replace

How can i update data using replace or regex-like method from

```
id | jdata
---------------
01 | {"name1":["number","2"]}
02 | {"val1":["number","12"],"val2":["number","22"]}
```

to

```
id | jdata
---------------
01 | {"name1":2 }
02 | {"val1": 12,"val2":22 }
```

I need to make a proper json entry for numbers and replace an array with a number from that array. Column "jdata" can have any number of similar attributes from the example. Something similar to this would do:

```
UPDATE table SET jdata = REPLACE(jdata, '["number","%d"]', %d);
```

Comment: When reading [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract), and some [FIDDLING](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bfca54a1c278d85b9274f50839b379a), this should not be that hard.  And I even doubt that you need `regex` for this.

Comment: I don't know in advance the number of JSON attributes @Luuk

Comment: What do you know about the attributes ?

Comment: I know that the data string has the format: {..., "ALNUM":["number", "DIGIT"], ...}. ALNUM - Alphanumeric characters, DIGIT - Digit characters, other as is it @Luuk

Comment: I did do an `edit` on my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. The long, more clumsy way, using [JSON_ARRAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array):

```
UPDATE table1,
(
   SELECT
      id,
      JSON_EXTRACT(jdata, "$.name1[0]") as A,
      JSON_EXTRACT(jdata, "$.name1[1]") as B,
      JSON_EXTRACT(jdata, "$.val1[0]") as C,
      JSON_EXTRACT(jdata, "$.val1[1]") as D,
      JSON_EXTRACT(jdata, "$.val2[0]") as E,
      JSON_EXTRACT(jdata, "$.val2[1]") as F
   FROM table1
) x 
SET jdata = CASE WHEN table1.id=1 THEN JSON_ARRAY("name1",x.B)
                                  ELSE JSON_ARRAY("val1",x.D,"val2",F) END
WHERE x.id=table1.id;
```

2. Or using [JSON_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace):

```
update table1
set jdata = JSON_REPLACE(jdata, "$.name1",JSON_EXTRACT(jdata,"$.name1[1]")) 
where id=1;

update table1
set jdata = JSON_REPLACE(jdata, "$.val1",JSON_EXTRACT(jdata,"$.val1[1]"),
                                "$.val2",JSON_EXTRACT(jdata,"$.val2[1]")) 
where id=2;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=832059460a48208078c6c1427c708b06)    for both options

EDIT:  To get more depth in the query, you can start with below, and create a new JSON message from this stuff without the `number`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 as (
   select 0 as x
   union all
   select x+1 from cte1 where x<10
   )
select 
   id,
   x,
   JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jdata),CONCAT("$[",x,"]"))) j,
   JSON_EXTRACT(jdata,CONCAT("$.",JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jdata),CONCAT("$[",x,"]"))))) v,
   JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdata,CONCAT("$.",JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jdata),CONCAT("$[",x,"]"))),"[0]"))) v1,
   JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdata,CONCAT("$.",JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jdata),CONCAT("$[",x,"]"))),"[1]"))) v2
from table1
cross join cte1
where x<JSON_DEPTH(jdata) 
  and not JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jdata),CONCAT("$[",x,"]")) is null
order by id,x;
```

output:

| id | x | j | v | v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | name1 | ["number", "2"] | number | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | val1 | ["number", "12"] | number | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | val2 | ["number", "22"] | number | 22 |

This should take care of JSON message which also contains values like `val3`, `val4`, etc, until a maximum depth which is now fixed to 10 in  `cte1`.

EDIT2:  When it is just needed to remove the "number" from the JSON message, you can also repeat this UPDATE until all "number" tags are removed  (you can repeat this in a stored procedure, I am not going to write the stored procedure for you )

```
update 
   table1, 
   ( WITH RECURSIVE cte1 as (
   select 0 as x
   union all
   select x+1 from cte1 where x<10
   ) select * from cte1 )x

set jdata = JSON_REMOVE(table1.jdata, CONCAT("$.",JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jdata),CONCAT("$[",x,"]"))),"[0]"))
where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdata,CONCAT("$.",JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jdata),CONCAT("$[",x,"]"))),"[0]"))) = "number"
```

An example, where I do run the update 2 times, is in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65b0d5bf91fd7210b73ce3221255f39a)

Comment: This answer also is a great example why it is a bad idea to "just use JSON columns" instead of doing proper database normalization.

Comment: Indeed, it is... 

Comment: This looks like a powerful solution, but unfortunately doesn't answer my question. @Luuk

Comment: @AngryFox: I added an UPDATE statement, with which you can solve your problem.

Comment: BTW:  checking if the tag "number" still exists can be done with: `select id, jdata, json_contains(jdata,'{"name1": "number"}') AS Contains from table1;`

Comment: @Luuk: I get an error: Error SQL (3143): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 10. if I try to escape ($.name to '$."name"'), then the character position number changes(10 > 1 > 19). I can't figure out why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AngryFox: I can only help when I know how the json looks like where the error is occurring.  One reason is that it has `val1` to more than `val9` (i.e. `val10`) or any number larger.